# Correct result but warnings that longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two functions with optional filtering (simplified):

```
f <- function(df, categories=NULL) {
    df %>% filter(is.null(categories) || category %in% categories))
}

g <- function(df, categories=NULL) {
    df %>% filter(is.null(categories) || any(categories == category))
}
```

I then do:

```
compare(f(x, c('a', 'b')), g(x, c('a', 'b')))
microbenchmark(f(x, c('a', 'b')), g(x, c('a', 'b')), times = 10)
```

on a large dataset. The output of the two functions is identical. There is actually some filtering going on: `unique(x$category)` shows several other values. However, `g` shows warnings for the object lengths. `g` benchmarks faster than `f` despite the warnings (which I think are probably expensive).

Is there a better way to write/optimise this, or at least suppress the warnings if this is safe?

Comment: This might be a better question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you sure? As I said, the output is correct and identical. `FALSE || FALSE` would not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` needs to get a vector with length equal to that of `df`. `any()` will always require in a vector of length 1. Bottomline is that `g()` does something different than `f()`

Have a look at this example

```
df <- data_frame(category = letters)
categories <- c("b", "a")
df$category %in% categories
categories == df$category
any(categories == df$category)
```

This is the correct way of doing it

```
f <- function(df, categories=NULL) {
  if (is.null(categories)) {
    df
  } else {
    df %>% filter(category %in% categories))
  }
}
```